# Install bootstrap theme into Rails 4 app - Issue with javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I downloaded a theme from `WrapBootstrap.com` and am trying to implement it into a new rails 4.1 application.

I was given four directories - css,fonts,img, and js. I was also given the `index.html` file.

I copied the `index.html` file over into my app and am routing to it. I then took the contents of each directory given to me and placed it in the appropriate assets directory:

`css` went to `stylesheets`, `img` went to `images`, `js` went to `javascripts`. I am not sure what to do with the `fonts` directory.

Then, I had a lot of requirements like this in my `index.html.erb` file:

These existed for both javascript and css. I took all of them out and replaced it with these lines of code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

And I have this in each of the application.css and application.js files:

```
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

and

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

Now, it appears that the CSS is rendering correctly. However, the JS files are not loading at all. I can take them out of the app entirely and I get the same result.

What am I missing here? The js files are in the asset directory, they are being required in `application.js`, and I have included `application.js` in my `index.html.erb` file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have external assets that are going to be used in your app, the Rails convention is to put them in the `vendor/assets` path. You can copy the corresponding files to their directories. The `fonts` should be inside the `stylesheets` folder.

Then in your application.js add this line (one for each file you have):

`//= require name-of-js-file-without-extention`

And in your application.css add this:

`*= require  name-of-css-file-without-extention`

At this point your css and js should be working :)